# Kaehler differentials of tensor products over another ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, kahler-differentials

Is this result well-known (or even true)?
Let
\begin{align*}
f:A & \to B\\
g:A & \to C
\end{align*}
 be homomorphisms of finitely generate $k$-algebras and let

$R=B\otimes_{k}C$ and 
 $S=B\otimes_{A}C$

Then there is a surjective homomorphism
$$
\xi:R\to S
$$
and
$$
\Omega_{S/k}=S\otimes_{B}\Omega_{B/k}\oplus_{\Omega_{A/k}}S\otimes_{C}\Omega_{C/k}
$$
Where the $\oplus$ with a subscript represents a push-out.

Comment: why do you think that it is true? maybe you can kindly give a non-trivial example?

Comment: That is true, but it follows from two other more primitive results.  First, $\Omega_{B/A}$, resp. $\Omega_{C/A}$, is the cokernel of the natural map $B\otimes_A \Omega_{A/k} \to \Omega_{B/k}$, resp. $C\otimes_A \Omega_{A/k} \to \Omega_{C/k}$, cf. Proposition II.8.3A, p. 173, *Algebraic geometry*, R. Hartshorne.  Second, $\Omega_{S/B}$ is isomorphic to $S\otimes_C \Omega_{C/A}$, resp. $\Omega_{S/A}$ is isomorphic to $S\otimes_B \Omega_{B/A}$, cf. Proposition 8.2A.  Finally, using Proposition 8.3A once more, the result follows.

Comment: Thank you! My proof simply uses the conormal exact sequence corresponding to the map $\xi$.